# browser.pages() does not resolve in puppeteer script

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, automation, puppeteer

End goal is to close all tabs by domain/subdomain name in Chrome.

I launched chrome with this:

```
launch_chrome_w_flag() {
  (/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 &> /dev/null &) & &> /dev/null

}
```

turns out there are a lot of Chrome processes on machine like this:

```
% ps aux | grep 'remote-debugging-port=9222' | wc -l
      28
```

and most were launched normally (with the Chrome.app application).

and then my Puppeteer script looks like:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function closeMatchingTabs(domains) {
    // Connect to an existing instance of Chrome
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserURL: 'http://localhost:9222',
        defaultViewport: null,
    });

    console.log('connected');
    const pages = await browser.pages(); // IT GETS STUCK HERE, NEVER RESOLVES

    console.log('tab count:', pages.length);

    for (const page of pages) {
        const url = await page.url(); // Get the URL of the tab

        console.log(url);

        // Check if URL matches any of the domains
        if (domains.some(domain => url.includes(domain))) {
            console.log('closing page:', url);
            await page.close(); // Close the tab if it matches
        }
    }

    console.log('done with pages.')
    // Do not close the browser as it's an existing instance
    browser.disconnect()
}

// Example usage
closeMatchingTabs(['example.com', 'sub.example.com']).then(v =>{
    console.log('done');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
})
```

but the problem is that my script gets stucked at the STUCK HERE line and never resolves. Anyone know why that might be? It does connect to an instance (although I don't know how all instances can listen on the same port?)